# Can I map keyboard layouts to different applications?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Is it possible in Ubuntu (I am using 12.04) to change the keyboard layout based on the current active application? E.g have one default layout and one other for a number of specified layouts?

I have tried opened certain applications, changed the layout and noticed that the layout switches as I change program. It doesn't seem to be consistent over time though.